# using postgresql group by how do i create 2 or more columns from one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PG admin to run a query. i have (for e.g.) 3 column as below in table named tbl.

```
| Payor | Event_id| event_Status|
|-------|---------|-------------|
| canada| 100     | show        |
|greenland|200    | no show     |
|canada | 300     | no show     |
|Italy  | 400     | show        |
```

I need to create a query that give a table like below

```
| Payor | count(distinct Event_id))| count(event_Status= show))|count(event_Status= no show))|
|-------|--------------------------|---------------------------|-----------------------------|
| canada| 2                        |   1                       |1                            |
|greenland|1                       |   0                       |1                            |
|Italy  |   1                      | 1                         |0                            |
```

I have this query to return as below, but it does return anything:

```
select 
    payor, 
    (select count(distinct event_id) 
     from tabl 
     where event_Status like 'Show%' 
     group by payor) as sh,
    (select count(event_status) 
     from tabl 
     where event_Status like 'Show%' 
     group by payor) as sts,
    (select count(distinct event_id) 
     from tabl 
     where event_Status like 'No Show%' 
     group by payor) as ns
    (select count(event status) 
     from tabl 
     where event_Status like 'No Show%' 
     group by payor) as nsts
from tabl;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Look into using `SUM(CASE WHEN [your conditions] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` to calculate your measures, combined with `GROUP BY payor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. Also, I would avoid using "like" if at all possible. Based on your sample data, you would not match "show" to "Show" unless you use the `ilike` function, or force the case.

```
select payor, 
 count(distinct event_id) as events, 
 sum(case when event_status = 'show' then 1 else 0 end) as events_show, 
 sum(case when event_status = 'no show' then 1 else 0 end) as events_no_show
from my_table
group by 1
```

[Fiddle found here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ujyE4zWLUduRi6vMP1dE1/0).

**EDIT**:

Based on your comment below, you are wondering about subqueries too. I typically use CTEs, which could look like this:

```
with e_show as (
  select payor, 
  count(event_id) as events
  from my_table
  where event_status = 'show'
  group by 1
  ),
  e_no_show as (
    select payor, 
    count(event_id) as events
    from my_table
    where event_status = 'no show'
    group by 1
    )
select t.payor, 
 count(distinct event_id) as events, 
 es.events as events_show, 
 ens.events as events_no_show
from my_table t
left join e_show es
   on t.payor = es.payor
left join e_no_show ens
   on t.payor = ens.payor
group by 1,3,4;
```

Comment: Alternatively: `count(*) filter (where event_status = 'show') as events_show`

Comment: thanks @isolated . i have one more question. can you please tell me how i could do this by using subqueries? also following query also worked for me: with sh as
(select payor, count(event_id) as show_ from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'Show%' group by payor),
ns as
(select payor, count(event_id) as no_show_ from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'No Show%' group by payor)

select sh.payor, sh.show_, no_show_ from sh full join ns on sh.payor = ns.payor;    but how could I use subquery for this?

Comment: thanks for helping. both queries you mentioned here are helpful for me.